# How to bind service only after permission is granted?

Tags: android, geolocation, google-play-services, android-location

### Background

I'm experiencing a known issue with a Google sample app for android play location using a foreground service.

In https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/issues/91, it is explained that

> The service should not be bound before the permission is granted.

In relation to the `bindService` line (151) at the bottom of `onStart()`:

```
bindService(new Intent(this, LocationUpdatesService.class), mServiceConnection,
Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

### Question

How do I make sure that permission has been granted before running `bindService`?

### Attempts to fix:

I've tried putting it in a conditional like this:

```
if (checkPermissions()) {
            // Bind to the service. If the service is in foreground mode, this signals to the service
            // that since this activity is in the foreground, the service can exit foreground mode.
            bindService(new Intent(this, LocationUpdatesService.class), mServiceConnection,
                    Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        }
```

But now I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void blah.blah.LocationUpdatesService.requestLocationUpdates()' on a null object reference
```

Which I assume is because the `mService.requestLocationUpdates();` function `onClick` is being run without the service being bound.

Any help is appreciated!

PS: I'm a total noob in Android.

Comment: I has nothing to to do with permission. You're probably running requestLocationUpdates before getFusedLocationProviderClient

Comment: search for "android service life cycle". cheers

Comment: @saiedVanguard But there isn't any mention to `getFusedLocationProviderClient` in the MainActivity?

Comment: @saiedVanguard I haven't edited the code from the google sample at all, other than for testing... Other's in the github issue linked have mentioned that binding only after the permission is granted fixed the problem. I just don't know exactly how to do that... Thanks.

Comment: which MainActivity?

Comment: @saiedVanguard This one... https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationUpdatesForegroundService/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdatesforegroundservice/MainActivity.java

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165789/discussion-between-saied-vanguard-and-helpinghand).

Comment: @saiedVanguard I read through the issue again and tried the solution posted by someone else... It worked! See my answer below. Thanks for your help!

Comment: perfect! good luck!

Answer (score 0):

By removing the `getLastLocation` call within the `LocationsUpdateService.java` file, it runs correctly. Apparently I have to read better:

> In LocationUpdateService.java, inside onCreate(), remove the
>   getLastLocation() call. The app runs just fine without it.
>
> The problem is that the user hasn't yet had the chance to grant the
>   Location runtime permission, and before they do the service is bound
>   and onCreate() runs, which requires that permission.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/issues/91#issuecomment-321841452